# Having some issues saving a user preferences to a profile

Tags: angular

So I have a checkbox that allows users to opt into emails but all I am getting is a error and I'm not sure why, it is hitting the catch statement however

TS:

```
submit = () => {
    if (this.profile) {
      this.userService.updateMarketingPreferences(this.communicationSelected).toPromise().then((a: boolean) => {
        if (a) {
          if (this.profile) {
            this.profile.IsRegisteredForWellbeingNewsletter = this.communicationSelected;
            
          }
          this.sharedService.getUserProfile(true);
          this.appService.openSnackBar(this.communicationSelected
            ? 'Successfully opted in for receiving marketing emails'
            : 'Successfully opted out of receiving marketing emails');
           }
      }).catch((e: any) => {
        console.log(e);
        this.appService.openSnackBar('Something went wrong.');
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Its hitting the catch each time and displaying the message instead

Comment: Is your API call getting successful?